# Combination of numpy and multiprocessing Queues disturbs ordering of the queue

Tags: python, numpy, queue, multiprocessing, task-queue

I am using the follwing pattern to do multiprocessing:

```
    for item in data:
        inQ.put(item)

    for i in xrange(nProcesses):
        inQ.put('STOP')
        multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(inQ, outQ)).start()

    inQ.join()
    outQ.put('STOP')

    for result in iter(outQ.get, 'STOP'):
        # save result
```

Which works fine. But if I send a numpy array through the `outQ`, the `'STOP'` does not end up in the end of `outQ`, causing my result fetching loop terminating to early.

Here is some code to reproduce the bahaviour.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def worker(inQ, outQ):
    for i in iter(inQ.get, 'STOP'):
        result = np.random.rand(1,100)
        outQ.put(result)
        inQ.task_done()
    inQ.task_done() # for the 'STOP'

def main():
    nProcesses = 8
    data = range(1000)

    inQ = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    outQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for item in data:
        inQ.put(item)

    for i in xrange(nProcesses):
        inQ.put('STOP')
        multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(inQ, outQ)).start()

    inQ.join()
    print outQ.qsize()
    outQ.put('STOP')

    cnt = 0
    for result in iter(outQ.get, 'STOP'):
        cnt += 1
    print "got %d items" % cnt
    print outQ.qsize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you replace the `result = np.random.rand(1,100)` with something like `result = i*i` the code works as expected.

What is happening here? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I would have expected the `outQ.put()` after the `inQ.join()` to do what I want, since the `join()` blocks until all processes have done all `put()`s.

On workaround working for me is doing the result fetching loop with `while outQ.qsize() > 0`, which works find. But I read `qsize()` is not reliable. Is it only unreliable while different processes are running? Would it be to secure for me to rely on `qsize()` after having done the `inQ.join()`?

I expect some people to propose to use `multiprocessing.Pool.map()`, but I'm getting pickle errors, when doing that with numpy arrays (ndarrays).

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Did you test it to see if plain old threading.Thread suffers the same issues?

Comment: I was using threading first, but I used it to do tar.gz reading which is implemented in python, which means threading won't help because of the GIL. Using threading and Queue.Queue seems to work, yes.

Answer (score 2):

numpy arrays use rich comparisons. So a=='STOP' returns a numpy array, not a bool, and that numpy array cannot be coerced to a bool. Under the covers, iter(outQ.get, 'STOP') is doing just that comparison and probably treating the exception when it tries to convert the result to a bool as False. You will have to do a manual while loop, pull items from the queue, check if isinstance(item, basestring) before comparing it to 'STOP'.

```
while True:
    item = outQ.get()
    if isinstance(item, basestring) and item == 'STOP':
        break
    cnt += 1
```

Checking for qsize() will probably also work fine because no other process is adding to the queue after the input queue is joined.

Comment: Does it fix the problem for you?

Comment: No, it looks like there is something else going on. Probably the time it takes to serialize the result items is interfering with the ability of the queues in the remote processes to push them into the main process. Thus you add 'STOP' to the queue in the main process before all the results actually come in. Try outQ.put([i]*1000) and you will see the same effect. Try "while not outQ.empty():" instead of using a 'STOP' sentinel. Avoid .qSize() because it does not work on all platforms.

Comment: You're right with the [i]*1000. I thought serialization would be finished, when the program does `inQ.task_done()`, why isn't that so? I tried `empty()` but it fails, too. Sometimes it is true where `qsize() > 0`. I don't get what's happening behind the scenes there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know how many items to expect from `outQ`, another work-around would be to wait for that number of items explicitly:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import Queue

N=100

def worker(inQ, outQ):
    while True:
        i,item=inQ.get()
        result = np.random.rand(1,N)
        outQ.put((i,result))
        inQ.task_done()

def main():
    nProcesses = 8
    data = range(N)
    inQ = mp.JoinableQueue()
    outQ = mp.Queue()    

    for i,item in enumerate(data):
        inQ.put((i,item))

    for i in xrange(nProcesses):
        proc=mp.Process(target=worker, args=[inQ, outQ])
        proc.daemon=True
        proc.start()

    inQ.join()
    cnt=0
    for _ in range(N):
        result=outQ.get()
        print(result)
        cnt+=1
        print(cnt)      
    print('got {c} items'.format(c=cnt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question, but solves the problem. And oh my god, I should have discovered that so much earlier! Thank you very much!

Comment: @unutbu: Did you actually use that module? It looks really messy to me.

Comment: @chuck: I haven't had a need to use it for serious work yet, but the code above works, yes? What about the module seems messy to you?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of outcommented lines of code on the first glance. It seems to require Cython and I don't see anything documented like what I have to look out for while using it. Also the readme file seems to be damaged. Did you have the experience that it just works?

Comment: @unutbu: It fails for 1000x10000 matrices, that's only 80 MB, I want to go at least up to 10GB. I guess the shared memory section is just not large enough?

Comment: @chuck: Hmm, yes, I'm seeing the same problem. There is a simple workaround which doesn't use `outQ.qsize`: how about just call `outQ.get()` `N` times, since after all, you know how many items to expect?